# How do I watch a state param in angular-ui-router when setting reloadOnSearch=false

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a page that shows a large table which features sorting, filtering etc. I "save" the parameters (for which column to sort, which filters apply) to the URL so that these things are contained in the browser history and one can go back or send a link to someone else that includes all parameters. To manipulate the URL without causing a reload I set reloadOnSearch=false to my ui router state.

In large parts that works well: I can send the link to someone else and if I follow a link that leads away from my table page I can use the back button of my browser and end up with the same table using the same settings as before.

However if I manipulate a parameter (search or stateParam, does not matter) while I am already on the desired state... E.g. clicking a link or by manually editing the browser's address bar this has absolutely no effect. This is even true if I use the "back" button. The parameters in the URL change, but the view does not update.

I don't want a full fledged reload to happen because of a stateParam change, but I still want to get noticed.

I tried the following to get noticed:

```javascript
$scope.$watch(function() {
  return $stateParams['someStateThatMightChange'];
}, function(newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal !== oldVal) {
    alert('Hey, I have been changed!');
  }
});
```

However if I manipulate the URL so that `someStateThatMightChange` changes, nothing happens. The alert does not show. What is the correct way to watch stateParameters?

Comment: You Need to subscribe to the routechangestart event.

Comment: @Elisa: The routechangestart event does not give access to state parameters (except by parsing the url myself which I currently do by watching $location.path() and is a messy hack) or is there there some possibility I missed?

Comment: I need a solution to this as well. If I use the browser back button or click an href and the url is the same as the current state url, but with different params, I need to be notified that the params have changed so i can fetch data.  On $locationChangeStart seems ugly.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried - for example?

`$scope.$watch(function () {
            return $state.params.tabId;
        }, function (newParams, oldParams) {
            console.log(newParams, oldParams);
            if (newParams !== oldParams) {
                alert('Hey, I have been changed!');
            }
        });`

Answer (score 2):

Have you has a looked at the $locationChangeStart event? It will get called when ever the url get changed:

```
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart',function(){
        console.log('$locationChangeStart called');
    })
```

It may not be a good solution since it gets called when ever the URL changes which probably isn't what you want but it may help.